# Find empty strings in dataframe with nullable booleans

Tags: pandas

I have code that looks for missing values in any arbitrary dataframe. For my purposes, empty means either null or an empty string.  Here's an example that works as intended:

```
s1 = pd.Series(name="Strings", data=['aa', 'bb', ''], dtype=str)
s2 = pd.Series(name="Ints", data=[1, 2, 3], dtype=int)
s3 = pd.Series(name="Floats", data=[1.1, 2.2, np.nan], dtype=float)
df = pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], axis="columns")
empty = (df == '') | df.isnull()
```

Let's add another column with nullable booleans:

```
s4 = pd.Series(name="Nullable_Booleans", data=[True, False, pd.NA], dtype="boolean")
df = pd.concat([s1, s2, s3, s4], axis="columns")
empty = (df == '') | df.isnull()
```

Now the test for empty strings breaks:

```
TypeError: values should be boolean numpy array. Use the 'pd.array' function instead
```

What is good way to inspect any arbitrary dataframe for empty strings when the dataframe may contain nullable booleans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
empty = (df == '') | df.isnull()
```

with:

```
empty = (df.astype('object') == '') | df.isnull()
```

empty:

```
   Strings   Ints  Floats  Nullable_Booleans
0    False  False   False              False
1    False  False   False              False
2     True  False    True               True
```